# Its possible have two common?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

im newest on Yii2. I know that yii2 advanced have a specific structure with 3 application (console, backend, frontend) and one core (common), and I can create others applications (secondFrondEnd, otherBackend, etc).

I investigated but I can't find information about is possible create a second common, or have any idea to create a structure that implement a estructure base->common->apps?? Idea its when I'll use gii crud, only overwrite the base with database changes, and common use to implement my specific methods.

Comment: You could create and 'ext' (extended) version models in /common/models/ext. So when you create models with gii, it will create in /common/models and your extended versions instead are in /common/models/ext.

Comment: Describe additional details for which reason you want to create "secondFrondEnd", "otherBackend", "second common" and other applications? Probably there is another way to solve your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem. I create a gii template that create a common/models/class and common/model/_base/baseclass. The class extends for base, and base class have a default code that gii generate.